# Jquery on click not responding to clicks from an appended html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this page http://zoo-keeper-objects-53412.bitballoon.com/ for my wap website. I have several buttons that append a form group to a div with id space. This is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $('#log').on('click', function(e) {
      alert('this connected');
       e.preventDefault();
       window.loading_screen.finish();
      });

      function login(){
      $('#space').html('<div class="row"><div class="" style="margin-right:15%; margin-bottom: 2%; margin-left:15%; border:3px solid white;"><form><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"><br/><label for="inputEmail">Telephone Number</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"> </div><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"> <label for="inputPassword">Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"> </div><button type="button" id="log" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button> </form><br/></div></div>');
      }

      function reset(){
      //window.loading_screen.finish();
      $('#space').html('<div class="row"><div class="" style="margin-right:15%; margin-bottom: 2%; margin-left:15%; border:3px solid white;"><form><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"><br/><label for="inputEmail">Telephone Number</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"> </div><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"> <label for="inputPassword">Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"> </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Reset Password</button> </form><br/></div></div>');
      }

      function join(){
      //window.loading_screen.finish();
      $('#space').html('<div class="row"><div class="" style="margin-right:15%; margin-bottom: 2%; margin-left:15%; border:3px solid white;"><form><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"><br/><label for="inputEmail">Telephone Number</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email"> </div><div class="form-group" style="margin-right:15%; margin-left:15%;"> <label for="inputPassword">Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"> </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Join</button> </form><br/></div></div>');
      }

      window.loading_screen = window.pleaseWait({
        logo: "img/logo.png",
        backgroundColor: '#f46d3b',
        loadingHtml: "<div id='space'></div> <button class='btn btn-success' onclick='login()'>Login</button> <button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='reset()'>Reset</button> <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='join()'>Join</button> "
      });

    </script>
```

The buttons do append the form group as expected but when i try to click the buttons of the appended html element, the on click event handler does not react. This is the code specifically

```
$('#log').on('click', function(e) {
      alert('this connected');
       e.preventDefault();
       window.loading_screen.finish();
      });
```

How can i have the button click respond to my clicks?.

Comment: And no duplicate ids

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, there will be no duplicate ids in that code as the functions replace the html inside space so therefore they will not repeat.  Mongo, have a read of this - [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) it will explain why the answer below from zuluk works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click',"#log", function(e) {
  alert('this connected');
  e.preventDefault();
  window.loading_screen.finish();
});
```

`.on()` needs the action and the element.